# How to change data from long to wide form in Java

Tags: java, transformation

I have a list of results of a series of votes (in long form), for example:

```
List<String[]> results=new ArrayList<>();

Vote | User | Poll
Yes  | 121  | 1     //each poll is on its own line
No   | 123  | 1
Yes  | 121  | 2
```

and I am trying to get my data to wide form:

```
Poll1Vote | Poll2Vote | User
Yes       | Yes       | 121    //this has all polls on one line for user 121
No        | NULL      | 123
```

Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: Could whoever voted to close this explain why it is unclear?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to transform that specific data (with more String[3] entries)?  (I'm not a close vote)

Comment: Yes, I've never tried to do stats in Java before and I am having trouble formatting the data correctly

Comment: Are you looking for a way to print the data in that format, or to change the ArrayList contents?

Comment: change the arraylist content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that will reformat the data

This is assuming your data is `{["Yes", "121", "1"], ...}`

You may need some minor adjustments if your data is formatted as `{["Vote", "User", "Poll"], ["Yes", "121", "1"], ...}`

---

This function works by first figuring out the `User` and `Poll` sets

Once it knows how many total users (output List length) and total polls (output Array lengths), it can match pairs of them together and build the output

```
List<String[]> format(List<String[]> input)
{
    List<String[]> output = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Set<String> users = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> pollSet = new HashSet<String>();
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(String[] row : input) //figure out how many users and polls there are
    {
        users.add(row[1]);
        pollSet.add(row[2]);
        data.put(row[1] + "_" + row[2], row[0]); //link user_poll to Yes/No data
    }

    String[] polls = pollSet.toArray(new String[0]); //make the set be an array for easier access
    Arrays.sort(polls); //sort the polls here if you want to

    for(String user : users) //loop over users, since each row is 1 user
    {
        String[] row = new String[polls.length + 1]; //each row is poll1,poll2,...,pollN,user
        row[row.length - 1] = user;

        for(int i = 0; i < polls.length; i++)
            row[i] = data.get(user + "_" + polls[i]); //retrieve the Yes/No data for user_poll, no data fills in null
            //alternative if you want "NULL" instead of null
            //if((row[i] = data.get(user + "_" + polls[i]) == null)
                //row[i] = "NULL";

        output.add(row); //add completed row to the output
    }

    return output;
}
```